# Looking to show the latest datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is now working - I meant to ask before, How would I get a column that would
give us how many days ago was this last date of service?

```
select full_name, event_name, actual_date,
row_number() over(partition by ev.full_name order by ev.actual_date DESC) as row_num --<<--<<--
from event_expanded_view ev
where
ev.full_name is not Null and ev.category_code in('OTHER_ACT', 'CONTACTS', 'PEOPLEPLANS', 'PEOPLETESTS', 'PERSONREQ')

)
select full_name, event_name, actual_date from cte_ul_ev where row_num = 1
```

Comment: A SQL query begins with `select`, not with `row_number()`.

Comment: It looks like the code is missing some rows at the top (I'm guessing `;with cte_ul_ev as (select....`).

Comment: [edit] your question, @PasPalter , don't put updates in the comments.

Comment: Also, you say you've having trouble getting it to "compile", what is wrong with it? What error are you getting?

Comment: It's at the last 3 Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "ev.full_name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "ev.event_name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "ev.actual_date" could not be bound.

Comment: Do you really need a `DISTINCT` there too, when you're filtering to the first row per person? The `DISTINCT` will simply add extra overhead.

Comment: *"The multi-part identifier "ev.full_name" could not be bound."* because `ev` is the alias of `event_expanded_view ` within the CTE. You can't reference objects inside the CTE outside of it. Omit the alias, or alias your CTE and use that alias.

Comment: Remove the `ev.` prefix in the select clause: change `select ev.full_name, ev.event_name, ev.actual_date
from cte_ul_ev
where row_num = 1` to `select full_name, event_name, actual_date
from cte_ul_ev
where row_num = 1`

Comment: You should take a minute to take the tour, and read [ask]. You've edited the post to an entirely different question which means now the answer you've got (and the comments) makes no sense - no future reader will ever be able to benefit from this content. I would advise you to delete this post entirely and ask your new question in a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
;WITH
    cte_ul_ev AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            ev.full_name,
            ev.event_name,
            ev.actual_date,
            row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ev.full_name ORDER BY ev.actual_date DESC)    --<<--<<--
        FROM
            dbo.event_expanded_view ev
        WHERE
            ev.full_name IS NOT NULL 
            AND ev.category_code IN ('OTHER_ACT', 'CONTACTS', 'PEOPLEPLANS', 'PEOPLETESTS', 'PERSONREQ')
        )
SELECT
    ue.full_name,
    ue.event_name,
    ue.actual_date
FROM
    cte_ul_ev ue
WHERE
    ue.row_num = 1;
```